# Can propagation delays be simulated in Active-HDL?

Tags: fpga, verilog, lattice, activehdl

I'm using the Lattice Diamond licensed version of Aldec Active-HDL. The logic circuits I'm working with are complex enough that I believe propagation delays could have an impact on the actual function of the hardware.

Is there a way to enable a propagation delay in simulation? Or a generic Verilog way of introducing a delay like this?

Comment: post P&R netlist should already be annotated with these delays.

Comment: SDF back annotation. Your tool needs to calculate these delays an puts them in an SDF file.

Answer (score -1):

Yes. In Verilog you use the `#` operator to introduce delays in simulation. This is well documented on many web sites.

Comment: Not a delay, a propagation delay based on the number of gates used, etc. I suppose adding a delay to every gate instantiation would work, but not for higher level code.

Comment: You can add delays for any kind of assignment, you don't have to instantiate every gate. Your question didn't say anything about "delay based on the number of gates".